# Qualtrics slider

Tags: javascript, slider, qualtrics

In order to design a specific real-effort task in Qualtrics, I need the slider-value to disappear until the left mouse button is released by participants. I looked up everything related to my question on stackoverflow and elswhere, but I could not find anything suitable. I have no experience in coding whatsoever, here my attempt using java-script:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var mouseDown = 0;
document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
mouseDown = 1;
} 
document.body.onmouseup = function() {
mouseDown = 0;
}
if (mouseDown == 0) {
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}}
});
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a slider question (not constant sum or graphical slider) with Mobile Friendly unchecked?

Comment: Exactly, it is a slider question with Mobile Friendly unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty far off. You need to examine the html before you can write JavaScript to interact with it. jQuery simplifies the coding. Try the following.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var hiddenInput = null;
    jQuery("#" + this.questionId + " .track").mousedown(function(event) {   //add mousedown events to sliders
        hiddenInput = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input.ResultsInput:first');  //find associated display value
        hiddenInput.hide();
    });
    jQuery('.Skin').mouseup(function(event) {
        if(hiddenInput.length > 0) {    //hidden display value?
            hiddenInput.show();
            hiddenInput = null;
        }   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly fine. However, if I add multiple sliders in different blocks, releasing the mouse won't release the slider anymore.

Comment: See edited code above. I changed `jQuery(document)` to `jQuery('.Skin')` which solves the problem.